# How long is one year?

Tags: prison-architect

How long is one year in Prison Architect in terms of

- game days
- real life minutes when played at normal speed

Bonus points if you know the ratio between normal speed and max fast forward speed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in the [release notes for version 19](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=47811), and assuming it has not been changed since:

> ... one year sentence = 120 game hours (5 days)

In real time that is 2 hours because 1 game hour = 60 real seconds, *but only for a small map*.

If you look in the save game file for medium and large maps a `TimeWarpFactor` is added, with a value of 0.75 and 0.5 respectively, which changes how fast time passes.

Therefore:

```
            Game hour Real minute    Game year Real time
            --------- -----------    --------- ---------
Small map:      1    =    1m             1    =  2h 
Medium map:     1    =  1m:20s           1    =  2h 40m
Large map:      1    =    2m             1    =  4h
```

So when played at normal speed one game year can range from 2 to 4 hours depending on your starting map size.

As to the increased speeds on a small map, the `>>` speed is about 30s to one game hour (2x) and the `>>>` speed is about 12s to one game hour (5x). So you can divide down the times given above as appropriate.

Comment: Cool, didnt even know about the time warp.

Answer (score 1):

According to a similar question on Steam, one year is:

> 120 in-game hours, which is 5 in-game days.

120 hours is equivalent to 7,200 minutes in game minutes. Sadly, I don't know the ratio.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/233450/discussions/0/620695877214051786/

Comment: 120 real hours is 7200 real minutes, but 120 in game hours definetly isnt 7200 real minutes

Comment: oh right. sorry.